# Probability of substring in string with overlaps

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability that a substring of length *N* will appear in a longer uniformly distributed string from an alphabet of length *K* if the substring is allowed to repeat, (e.g. AAAA)?

I've seen some approximations to this that assume non-repeating substrings. I'd like to get a better grasp for this problem, but I can't seem to find the search terms. I expected to find something from Knuth.

I've found a SO post about the [Goulden-Jackson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926028/probability-of-a-substring-occurring-in-a-string) method, but it's difficult to understand. Any help on what this problem is called and where I can learn about it?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* A nice presentation of the  *Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method* is given in *[this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*. You might find the following  posts helpful:

- [Find a generating function for the number of strings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782724/find-a-generating-function-for-the-number-of-strings/1783033#1783033)
- [Ordered binary sequences of length n with no two consecutive 0's without using recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910186/ordered-binary-sequences-of-length-n-with-no-two-consecutive-0s-without-using-r/1910231#1910231)
- [When adding zero really counts …](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684421/when-adding-zero-really-counts)